# Trying to Create an AFM relationship by using GPFS protocol. Having error in cache side cluster

Tags: centos, cluster

I am trying to create an `AFM` relationship by using `GPFS` protocol. Having error in cache side cluster.

Steps of Home cluster :

1) Create a home cluster (cluster name - gpfs01).

2) Create a file system at the home cluster (filesystem name - gpfs01).

3) Enable remote access to the file system .

4) To configure the exported path at the home cluster for `AFM`.

Steps of Cache cluster :

1) Create a cache cluster (cluster name - gpfs02)

1) `mmchnode --gateway -N Node1`

2)  `mmstartup -a`

3)  `mmmount Device -a`

4)  Mount the home filesystem on the cache cluster remotely.

5)  When i am created `AFM` fileset and link it but still getting this error.

```
 [root@gpfs02 ~]# mmcrfileset gpfs02 singleWriter1  -p 
 afmtarget=gpfs:///gpfs/storage/ -p afmmode=sw --inode-space new

 mmcrfileset: File system gpfs02 belongs to cluster gpfs01.
 Command is not allowed for remote file systems.

 mmcrfileset: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to 
 determine 
 cause.


[root@gpfs02 ~]# mmcrfileset gpfs01 afm2 -p 
 afmtarget=gpfs:///gpfs/storage/ -p afmmode=sw --inode-space new

 mmcrfileset: [E] Invalid option specified: gpfs:///gpfs/storage/.
 The AFM target must be on a separate filesystem.

 mmcrfileset: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to 
 determine cause.
```

Answer (score 0):

First error -- You can only create filesets on the cluster owning the filesystem. So probably you should create a plain fileset on gpfs01 like this:

```
[root@gpfs01 ~]# mmcrfileset gpfs01 singleWriterHome1 --inode-space new
[root@gpfs01 ~]# mmlinkfileset gpfs01 singleWriterHome1 -J /gpfs/gpfs01/singleWriterHome1
```

It doesn't have to be a fileset on this side -- could also have been a plain directory.

Then on gpfs01 you will have to have the "gpfs01" filesystem defined as a remote mount, and mounted, f.ex. as /gpfs/gpfs01. Then you should be able to create an AFM cache in "gpfs02" by running:

```
[root@gpfs02 ~]# mmcrfileset gpfs02 afmsw1 -p afmtarget=gpfs:///gpfs/gpfs01/singleWriterHome1 -p afmmode=sw --inode-space new
```